# Допустимо "по-этому" в значении "таким образом"?

Tags: орфография

Можно ли использовать *по-этому* в значении 'таким образом'? (Мне интересно, правильно ли вообще когда-либо писать так – через дефис. Я просто предполагаю, что это возможно в след. случае.)

`Если вы хотите знать, как я думаю, то слушайте меня. Я думаю по-этому: скорее всего, Том – грабитель банка, а не Джон.`

Я понимаю, что надо писать *по этому*, если мы используем это словосочетание в значении 'с помощью / в соответствии с этим чем-то'.

`Я смог определить, кто ограбил банк, по этому: я посмотрел камеры видеонаблюдения.`

Comment: Поздравляю с первым вопросом по стилистике. "Можно ли использовать слово" — по части стилистики.

Comment: Для этого есть союз "так". Я смог, определить кто ограбил банк, так: я посмотрел в камеры видеонаблюдения. Так, вот так, вот так вот. Зачем еще сюда добавлять по-этому в такой странной форме, что нового он даст? Ну, есть вероятность, что если ты напишешь "по этому" или "по-этому" тебя поймут, но зачем нужен выдуманный союз который ничего нового не дает, а дублирует уже известные? Ну и есть еще таким образом=так/следующим образом. 
Да и вообще союз тут необязателен. Я понял, кто ограбил банк: я посмотрел камеры наблюдения. То есть ":" достаточно, для того, чтобы понять, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: Поэтому - это союз про следующий вывод, относительное будущее, а не про прошлое. Я посмотрел камеры видеонаблюдения, поэтому смог установить личность грабителя банка. Я смог установить личность грабителя банка, *поэтому(!?)* посмотрел в камеры видеонаблюдения... - очередная чепуха.

Comment: То есть: перепутаны функции синтаксиса - запятая, двоеточие; перепутаны функции союзов; как результат перепутано время.

Comment: На самом деле ты мог поставить любое слово(даже выдуманное) перед двоеточием, и эффект будет такой же. Леопольд-Тыквин смог ввести в заблуждение, того кто это прочитал, вау-таки-такс-брумс: он просто поставил двоеточие...

Comment: @Буратино Леопольд хочет повыпендриваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Наречия **«по-этому»** нет в словаре: приставка ***ПО*** пишется слитно (но не через дефис).
2. В этих предложениях нужно правильно использовать **указательные** местоименные слова.

(1) *Я думаю **так:** скорее всего, Том – грабитель банка, а не Джон*.
**Сравнить:** Скорее всего, Том – грабитель банка, а не Джон, **это** легко можно доказать.

(2) Я смог определить, кто ограбил банк, ***так***: я посмотрел камеры видеонаблюдения. **Сравнить:** *Я посмотрел камеры видеонаблюдения, **это** помогло мне сделать вывод.*

**Вывод:** «Так» здесь указывает на **следующее** предложение, а «это» - на **предыдущее** предложение.

**P.S.**  Можно, конечно, **задать вопрос:** почему приставка ***ПО*** пишется слитно, а не через дефис? Ведь есть же у нас наречия ***по-другому, по-одному, по-всякому***. Но это уже другая тема...

Comment: Тире не нужно по ударениям.

Comment: Какое тире, где тире?  В сохраняю тире, которое было в авторском тексте. И с каких пор вы ставите тире по ударениям, а не по правилам, как все добропорядочные пользователи)

Comment: Можно было бы подправить. Ведь очень интересный момент. С тире совсем другое произношение, которое не подходит.

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Еще одну проблему обсуждать? К тому же это не факт, что там нельзя поставить тире.

Comment: Чтобы всё было правильно. Используйте правило Лопатина, в котором сказано про ударения! А пунктами все случаи не перечислить...

Comment: А да, можно, но тогда получается это: *Я думаю так: скорее всего, Том — это грабитель банка, а не Джон.* Странная структура, не так ли? Вряд ли это задумывалось.

Comment: Выделяете "Том"  логическим подчеркиванием – и пауза  вам обеспечена. А где у Лопатина говорится про ударения, я считала, что он такой анализ не использует. Вы теперь на Лопатина переключились, он ваше всё)  Какое непостоянство!

Comment: Нет, надо и "грабитель банка" выделить. В этой же теме, недавно узнал. Так мы же оба справочника используем. Они друг друга дополняют.

Comment: Можно всё выделить... Такие решения будут дополнять друг друга))

Comment: Ну так тогда другая структура (кривая): *Я думаю так: скорее всего, Том — это грабитель банка, а не Джон.* Тогда "а не Джон" — присоединение, нет цельного противопоставления.